# What is the relationship between DefaultInfo and PyInfo

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules

It's not clear to me what the difference between the DefaultInfo runfiles's transitive_files and PyInfo transitive_sources are. Are they redundant or is there an important difference?

For example, I have a custom starlark rule which I want to conform as a PyInfo provider, but I want to add an additional provider so I can't use the native py_library rule.

```
    transitive_sources = [dep[PyInfo].transitive_sources for dep in ctx.attr.deps]
    return struct(providers = [
        DefaultInfo(
            files = depset(sources + outs),
            runfiles = ctx.runfiles(files = sources + outs, transitive_files = transitive_sources)
        ),
        PyInfo(
            transitive_sources = depset(direct = sources + outs, transitive = transitive_sources),
            imports = depset(
                direct = [_path_join(ctx.workspace_name, ctx.label.package, im) for im in ctx.attr.imports],
                transitive = [dep[PyInfo].imports for dep in ctx.attr.deps]
            )
        ),
        _EggLibraryInfo(aditional_info="other stuff"),
    ])
```

I'm creating redundant depsets to satisfy these providers, which makes me think maybe I'm doing it wrong.

I have also tried another method of looping over all the `default_runfiles` of the deps, and using runfiles.merge for DefaultInfo. For simple cases, these methods appear equivalent, but I don't know if there are other scenarios where the approaches would diverge.

The PyInfo documentation could use a section on how transitive_sources fits into DefaultInfo, and why additional mechanisms outside of runfiles needs to be provided. https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/PyInfo.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DefaultInfo` is a known type to Bazel:

- `files` controls which files are built when you `bazel build` the target,
- `runfiles` defines which files need to be present in the sandbox when executing the target.

`PyInfo` is exclusively used by Python rules and is used to propagate metadata to consuming targets.

My guess is that the duplication is necessary because the values may differ, so removing the duplication will either mean Bazel doesn't build/include the right files, or consuming Python rules are missing information.

Comment: Would you say that PyInfo.transitive_files is always a superset of DefaultInfo.runfiles? And if so, should the PyInfo transitive_sources be constructed from DefaultInfo some how, or should these trees be completely independent? If not - is there an example to make the distinction clear?